# How can I install NSExceptionHandlers automatically on NSOperationQueues?

Tags: objective-c, multithreading, macos, cocoa, exception

long time lurker, first time poster.

I'm writing a cocoa app that makes heavy use of NSOperationQueues to manage background tasks. This app is a rewrite of a much older app that used manually managed NSThreads to accomplish similar things.

One of the requirements is that we trap/log all uncaught exceptions to avoid app termination. In the older version of the app, we would install exception traps all all threads using the NSExceptionHandler API. Now that we're a level of abstraction removed from threads, I don't have access to the thread object (in fact, I'm under the impression that the thread(s) used by a queue may change per operation invocation).

What's the recommended/best way to keep my app from crashing when a background operation fails?

Deployment is on Mac OS X 10.6 if that matters.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this for myself using the following:

```
NSInteger mask = (NSLogUncaughtExceptionMask| NSHandleUncaughtExceptionMask | NSLogUncaughtSystemExceptionMask | NSHandleUncaughtSystemExceptionMask | NSLogUncaughtRuntimeErrorMask | NSHandleUncaughtRuntimeErrorMask | NSLogTopLevelExceptionMask | NSHandleTopLevelExceptionMask);
[[NSExceptionHandler defaultExceptionHandler] setDelegate:[[MyExceptionHandler new] autorelease]];      
[[NSExceptionHandler defaultExceptionHandler] setExceptionHandlingMask:mask];
```

Details were found in the guide Exception Programming Topics, section "Controlling a program's Response to Exceptions"